# Creating an array list of names on SD Card Android

Tags: android, database, arraylist, sd-card

I am in the process of developing an android app, and I need a way for the user to enter a Name and then save this name to a .txt file in the SD card. When the user adds another name, this file should be modified to include that name. I was thinking of an array list, but I've been trying for some time on things to use but I'm not sure how. (I don't think an object output stream would work(?)). Also, I need the user to be able to read and access this file within the app.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You should check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal. These are the different options for storage in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a certain reason why you are using a .txt file? I would suggest you use a SQLite database for this particular project.

EDIT: Here is the one of the best articles you can find on building SQLite in android.

[Building a Database For Android](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is this possible without an SQLiteDatabase, only on the SD Card of the user? If not a txt file, can I use something else besides this SQLite Database

Comment: There arent many options availible for android. SQLite is the easiest and most effecient storage in android. Are you familiar with implementing this?

Comment: No I'm actually not. Could you direct me to some sample code or a helpful resource?

Comment: Sure if you want i can provide an example here.

Comment: Ive provided a great article to get you going. Just comment back here if you run into any problems. Ill be glad to answer them for you.

Comment: Also be sure to READ! As alot of people skip to the code. =) the reading content is VERY important to understand the concept. Its a relatively simple process though.